# Should all classes have a .equals and .hashcode method?

Tags: java, methods, equals, hashcode

I'm working on a unit testing project where the asserts call the .equals method. However the people on the project before didn't generate these methods.

Is it considered best practice to auto generate these methods as you code? Should all coders be doing this?

I was searching for more information on the .equals and .hashcode method and most of them seem to be geared towards how to implement or override them.

Comment: Depends on the purpose of the class. For many classes the "identity" as implemented by the `equals` and `hashCode` methods inherited from `Object` is just fine.

Comment: If you need to compare objects of those types, you need to override `equals`, and `hashCode`, also `hashCode` usually needs to be overridden when you are putting your objects into a hashmap ( but in most cases not necessary). Usually if one is overridden, other is also overridden.

Comment: It is never good practice to *auto generate* an `equals` method.  Few classes logically define their identity by all of their state fields, which I assume is what an auto generated `equals` method would do.  If instances are going to be checked for equality, write a sensible `equals` method and `hashCode` method by hand.

Comment: Don't rely on `equals` method for tests. What if your `equals` method always return `true`? Your test will be probably always green, even though it shouldn't. Use tools like shazamcrest (https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) that allow to easily compare objects without relying on `equals`/`toString` methods.

Comment: Do the tests in question pass?  If you override `equals()`, then those or similar tests might pass in cases where they currently would fail.  Should they?

Comment: @svasa some of your advice is contrary to best practice. One only overrides `equals` when value equivalence is needed. It's perfectly valid to compare objects with identity equivalence if that is the semantics of the type. One doesn't need to override `hashCode` only when using identity equality. If overriding `equals`, one must override `hashCode` and if implemented, `compareTo` to be consistent with it, and should override `toString` to match. `HashMap` is only one use case where this matters, not the only one.

Comment: @LewBloch Yes, you don't need `equals` when identity equivalence is enough, I was just citing an example where one wants to compare based on a certain field of the class for example.

Comment: @John, No they fail when I try and do a compare, even though the fields are the exact same. Could do a whole lot of assertEquals on the fields themselves rather than the object, but I feel that that would be against best practices

Comment: @Ej_840, my question is not whether two instances with the same field values compare equal, but rather whether they are *supposed* to compare equal.  Without additional information, it is by no means safe to assume that they should, or that it would be a good thing if they did.

Comment: @John, ah I see what you mean, yes, they are supposed to be equal. Not checking for if they are the same instance, but rather if they are logically equivalent. And that is a good point, something that Ill be keeping an eye out for when touching these two methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mostly a question of taste - if you don't expect to use the `equals` method (e.g., aren't using `assertEquals`, never mean to use this class as a key in a `Map`, etc), writing it means you may be writing dead code, and some conventions would advocate avoiding it.

Here, there doesn't seem to be a question - if you intend to use `assertEquals`, you need an the `equals` method implemented. If you're going to implement it, you should probably also implement `hashCode` in order to future proof your code against sneaky, hard to find, bugs.

Comment: You seem to suppose that the expectations of the assertions in the OP's tests are not congruent with the `equals()` implementation his classes inherit from `Object`.  It's not clear to me from the question that this is the case.

Comment: "if you intend to use assertEquals, you need an the equals method implemented." Why would that be? If `equals` is expected to check for identity and therefore not overridden, you can still use `assertEquals`.

Comment: It is not at all a "question of taste". "Taste" has absolutely nothing to do with it. That is invalid advice. It's a matter of semantics and determined entirely by engineering principles. Certainly nothing as vague and undefinable as "taste".

Comment: @Mureinik, Thanks! Was trying to get some perspective on what is considered good when handling this situation. So the takeaway that I got was, avoid generating .equals/.hashcode, unless you know you need it. Even if you may end up implementing it later, do it then, not now.

Comment: @Ej_840 that is not good engineering, to implement value semantics "then, not now". You should know from the very start if a type has value semantics or identity semantics. If you change the public interface (not `interface`) once your code is released, that is a Very Bad Thing ™. Your "takeaway" is backwards. Definitely design your type up front for whether you compare by identity or value. Do not do it later.

Answer (score 0):

Auto generating of these methods leads us to some standard implementation. One standard implementation is coded in Object: comparing links and a native hash code calculation.
Unless you can imagine some other standard implementation fitting for all entities in your project, you probably shoudn't auto generate equals and hash code: implement it manually, when you know all conditions of future comparation.